# HTML5 video tag with Internet Explorer and firefox

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, html5-video

I am developing a website which will have video on the front page. For this I was told to use html5 video player. So, I created a small html file to test if the video tag works. The code is below,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>    
<body>
<video width="320" height="240" controls="controls">
  <source src="FrontPageVideo.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  <source src="FrontPageVideo.webm" type="video/webm" />
  Can't play Video. Upgrade your brower
</video>     
</body>
</html>
```

This works ok with chrome, firefox and internet explorer 9.
So, I decided to use the code in my .NET MVC3 razor view. The code snippet is like,

```
<div>
    <video width="295" height="210" controls="controls">
        <source src="@(Url.Content("~/Media/FrontPageVideo.webm"))" type="video/webm" />
        <source src="@(Url.Content("~/Media/FrontPageVideo.mp4"))" type="video/mp4" />
            Can't Play Video. Upgrade your browser.
    </video>
</div>
```

But, I don't know why this code only works with chrome. Firefox and IE9 shows a black portion in the page with a cross sign.

Need help here.

Comment: Have you tried reversing the order of the `source` elements?

Comment: yes i did that. nothing happened.

Comment: How does the rendered HTML look?

Answer (score 0):

I can't post comments yet it looks like, but I recommend checking what document mode your second page is loading in in IE (not sure about Firefox, might be the same issue).  It sounds like the page might be loading in one of the older modes, because it doesn't have a DOCTYPE html token like in your first example.